# Arithmetical function comparable to sine function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elementary-proofs, arithmetic-functions

I was wondering if there exists or can we construct (using known arithmetic functions) an arithmetical function that has the same behaviour of the function sine or comparable to it (I mean that oscilates, changes regularly signs, periodic if it is necessary...).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to be explicit in what you call an arithmetic function; do you follow this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function

Comment: Yes Sir, I mean that definition.

Comment: $f(n) = 1 - 2\cdot (n \text{ mod } 2) $

Comment: Thanks for your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#%CE%BB(n)_%E2%80%93_Liouville_function) ($-1$ to the power of the number of prime divisors of $n$) could be a candidate for a "sine-like" function. It's not periodic, but it does oscillate, changing sign infinitely often, and has the same range $[-1,1]$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir for your answer.